# Recursive Mongo Find

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

So I want to find the names of people who are the partners of the current person.
My data looks like this:

```
{
    _id: objectId,
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
    partners: [objectId]
}
```

I have tried this aggregate/lookup - but it returns incorrect results

```
module.exports.getUserPartners = function( user_id, callback ) {

    const query = [
        {
            $unwind: "$partners"
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "people",
                localField: "partners",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "people_partners"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: { "_id": user_id }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                first_name: 1,
                last_name: 1
            }
        }
    ];
    People.aggregate( query, callback );

}
```

If my data looks like this:  (and I pass '123' as the user_id)

```
{
    _id: '123',
    first_name: "bob",
    last_name: "smith",
    partners: ['234','345']
},{
    _id: '234',
    first_name: "sally",
    last_name: "smartypants",
    partners: ['789']
},{
    _id: '345',
    first_name: "martin",
    last_name: "tall",
    partners: []
}
```

I get these results from the above aggregate lookup:

```
[{
    _id: '123',
    first_name: "bob",
    last_name: "smith"
},{
    _id: '123',
    first_name: "bob",
    last_name: "smith"
}]
```

when I EXPECT these results:

```
[{
    _id: '234',
    first_name: "sally",
    last_name: "smartypants"
},{
    _id: '345',
    first_name: "martin",
    last_name: "tall"
}]
```

> *NOTE - I added the $unwind based on recommendation form docs and this article
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#unwind-example

Comment: Look into aggregations and `$lookup`

Comment: See above for results of $lookup attempt

Comment: what is difference in your posted collection and the expected result?

Comment: note the names and the ids...the expected result should pull the name of the match for the partner...the actual result is returning the main persons record twice (the number of ids in the partner array).

Comment: Don't use `$unwind` here and use `$match` at the start of the pipeline.

Comment: Anthony - that match at the start was good advice, and I understand it as having to happen at the start of the pipeline - but mongo docs specify the undwind when you're comparing to a field that is an array - you have to flatten it... in the pipeline for the compare. reference the link to the docs in the post - a working aggregate was posted below by IftekharDani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this `aggregate` query. look like its complex.

```
db.getCollection('people').aggregate([
         {$match : {  "_id" : "123"} },
        {
   $unwind:
        {
          path:"$partners",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "people",
                localField: "partners",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "people_partners"
            }
        },
         {
       $unwind:
        {
          path:"$people_partners",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
        }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id : '$people_partners._id',
                first_name : '$people_partners.first_name',
                last_name : '$people_partners.last_name',

            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you - and I understand it...!! bonus